# Symfony 5: how to get option data from route rules

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony5

I would need to add the Options parameter along with the route. I have events in the eventListener before calling the controller and I want to modify the rights according to this option ...

I can list all routes and find an option in them, but the system of such routes will have several hundred, it would like to get to this directly at the route just visited.

How to do it?

[list all routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQqvv.png)

[route annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxJlL.png)

Comment: Options are really for internal use. Add this sort of info to the defaults section of the route definition then pull from the request with something like $request->attributes->get('system'); And don't use images in questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super easy solution, thanks!

```
if ($e->getRequest()->get('system') === null) { throw new BadRequestException(...)
```